# Laravel - DocBlock for view files

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I've just started one of my first bigger multi-developer project and want to make sure that I'm commenting everything correctly.

Is there a standard approach for commenting Laravel views? Or is it so self explanatory that it doesn't need comments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say the latter. See, typical view should contain as less logic as possible - so if there's a block that looks rather bad without a comment, it's actually a very strong reason for this block to be moved into a helper function (and that should be docblocked).

As for layout details, commenting it is usually quite redundant - and will only complicate things when you'll have to introduce some changes to it.

Besides, another major reason behind using DocBlock - ease of generating API documentation - isn't really applicable for views: there's no 'interface' provided.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use comments in Laravel's `Blade` view then you may use following syntax:

```
{{-- This comment won't be in the rendered HTML --}}
```

But, a `docblock` is basically a special type of commenting system that can provide verbose information about an element in your code, for example (maybe for a method or a function)

```
/**
 * Create a new driver instance.
 *
 * @param  string  $driver
 * @return mixed
 */
```

It may also contain a block of comment but in this case a `view` shouldn't contain this kind of complex code at all. While you may use simple hints like this:

```
<!-- Main loop starts -->
@foreach($items as $item)
    {{ ... }}
@endforeach
<!-- Main loop ends -->
```

Or you may also use a block like this:

```
{{--
    Some text goes here
    Some text goes here
--}}
```

But, it's better to use `{{-- comments --}}` because it won't be available in rendered `HTML`. If you have any complex code that should be in the view then you may consider to keep that in a helper file (`raina77ow` already mentioned it) and call that function from the `view, for example, this is a helper function I used inside my`view` but stored in a seperate helper file:

```
/**
 * Recursively loop the comments and return to view
 *
 * @param  Eloquent Collection  $comments
 * @param  string $view
 * @return string (HTML)
 */
function dumpComments($comments, $view = 'comment.comment_partial.comment')
{
    $commentList = '';
    foreach ($comments as $comment) {
        $commentList .= View::make($view)->with('comment', $comment);
    }
    return $commentList;
}
```

This is how I used it in my `view`:

```
@if($post->comments->count())
{{-- Begin comment List --}}
    <ul class="media-list"> {{ dumpComments($post->nestedComments) }} </ul>
{{-- End comment List --}}
@endif
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer, I was looking for how to actually docBlock that I was returning a view from a function. Thanks for the example as the i think it helps understand the relationship between commenting the view and the function that would return it.

Comment: I do have one question though, in the generated HomeController.php the return for a view is a Illuinate\Http\Response, should i be using that for returning a view?

Comment: If you return a view from a controller that will be turned into response by the Framework but in other cases where you are not returning the http response then you should just return the view.